# Rust Nom take_until with parser and not pattern

Tags: rust, markdown, nom

Using latest (v7) nom crate.

Trying to build a parser capable of extracting code blocks from markdown. In the flavor of markdown I need to support, a code block only ends if there is three grave/backtick characters on a line by themselves, excepting perhaps followed by whitespace.

Here is an example, where I replace backticks with single quotes (') to make editing with the StackOverflow markdown sane:

```
'''python
print("""
'''")
// this is all still a code block
'''
```

The obvious solution is to just use `take_until("'''")` however, that will end the take early, since that just does a search for the first occurrence of `'''` which is not accurate. I need the termination condition to be `tuple((tag(code_end), space0, newline))`.

The next obvious solution is to use regular expressions as the pattern in `take_until`... but I would prefer to avoid that. Is there any prebuilt parser (or available in another crate) that will take all until a parser returns `Ok`?

```
use nom::IResult;
use nom::combinator::opt;
use nom::sequence::{terminated, tuple};
use nom::bytes::complete::{tag, take_until};
use nom::character::complete::{newline, space0, alpha1};

fn code(i: &[u8]) -> IResult<&[u8], &[u8]> {
    let (input, _) = tuple((tag("'''"), opt(alpha1), tag("\n")))(i)?;
    let terminator = tuple((tag("'''"), space0, newline));
    let (input, contents) = terminated(take_until("'''"), terminator)(input)?;
    Ok((input, contents))
}

fn main() {
    let test = &b"'''python
print(\"\"\"
'''\"\"\"
// this is all still a code block
'''
";
    assert!(code(&test[..]).is_ok());
}
```

the above assertion will fail. However, if you remove the line with the three (''') single quotes, it will pass. This is because of the difference between `terminator` and `take_all("'''")`. What is my best pattern for solving this problem?

Thanks for any help. I have a feeling I'm missing something obvious or just doing something wrong. Let me know if anything isn't clear.

Here is a link to the above example in the Rust Playground for convenience: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d5459edded1e4258ba3e034658ea4acf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the proper combinator would be [`many_till`](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/multi/fn.many_till.html):

> Applies the parser f until the parser g produces a result.

That combined with `anychar` will return a `Vec<char>` for your code block.

I think there is no `anybyte` in nom, but you can easily write it yourself if you prefer to get `Vec<u8>`.

Or if you want to avoid allocating and want a slice referencing to the original slice, and don't mind a bit of unsafe you can ignore the consumed characters and take compute the slice from the start and end pointers ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2cd1b100bca97358dd5e3ed6803655d9)):

```
fn code(i: &[u8]) -> IResult<&[u8], &[u8]> {
    let (input, _) = tuple((tag("'''"), opt(alpha1), tag("\n")))(i)?;
    let terminator = tuple((tag("'''"), space0, newline));
    let start = input;
    let (input, (_, (end, _, _))) = many_till(map(anychar, drop), terminator)(input)?;
    let len = unsafe { end.as_ptr().offset_from(start.as_ptr()) as usize};
    Ok((input, &start[..len]))
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up implementing a safe version of your solution because, in my particular case, I can determine the offset from the original slice based on input/output length.